# How to check if a time series is I(1) in R?

Tags: r, time-series, cointegration

I'm testing the cointegration of two time series of stock prices using adfTest from fUnitRoots, but first I need to check if the series are I(1).

How can I check if a time series is I(1)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Dickey-Fuller test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test) by `DickeyFullerPValues` in `fUnitRoots`.

Comment: Thanks MansT. I'm using Augmented Dickey-Fuller to test the cointegration of both time series by testing if the linear combination of the two series is I(0). What's is the parameter in the function to choose I(1) and not I(0)?

Comment: Actually, using `adf.test` in `tseries` seems simpler. I(1) is the default in both cases, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

What you can also use is Phillips-Perron test `pp.test` and Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin (KPSS) test `kpss.test` from `library(tseries)`.